# Upgrade fail 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, data-recovery

I made a horrible mistake and upgraded from 12.04 (dual boot Win7) to 14.04 DIRECTLY, and it failed and I am left with a scrambled screen which does not respond to anything.

Any way I can recover my system?

Comment: Create backup first, in every attempt to do crucial thing to system. And just do reinstall, don't do upgrade if you want to change your Ubuntu version. This is my suggestion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal(`Ctrl`+`ALt`+T) and write the following command,

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Press `Enter` enter your user password when it asks you.

Things to Note

If you’re following this guide on April 17, 2014 then be aware that the whole process could take some time. Ubuntu 14.04 has only just been released and you won’t be the only person upgrading, so be prepared for the upgrade to take longer than usual to complete.

Also, while an LTS-to-LTS upgrade should preserve all your files it would be prudent to make a backup of any important documents, folders and photos before you begin. It’s rare for ‘direct upgrades’ to go wrong, but never say never.

[Source Link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04).